# Count of table before and after insert inside a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to check the count of a table before any changes happen and the count after the insert and match them inside the same trigger?

for ex: old.count and new.count (before and after insert) ?

Comment: Create a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER`. See my answer.

Comment: Note that such a count will only count rows that can be seen by the current session (i.e. the session will not see uncommitted rows from other sessions, and will see uncommitted rows in the current session). Be careful how your application interprets/uses these counts.

Answer (score 0):

> old.count and new.count (before and after insert)

Nothing stops you from using `SELECT COUNT(*)` in a before insert trigger. Of course, you won't do it in a after insert trigger, since a `select count(*)` on the same table on which an after trigger is defined would throw **mutating table error**. One way is **autonomous transaction**. But, in your case, it isn't that complex.

You could define a **BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER** and take the table count. The after insert count could be taken manually after the actual insert is done.

For example, I have a table t1 with one row. I have defined a before insert trigger on it, which would give me the table count before the insert happens.

```
SQL> DROP TABLE t1 PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t1 (A NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t1;

         A
----------
         1

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg
  2  BEFORE INSERT
  3  ON t1
  4  FOR EACH ROW
  5
  6  DECLARE
  7   val number;
  8  BEGIN
  9    SELECT COUNT(*)
 10    INTO val
 11    FROM t1;
 12
 13  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TABLE COUNT BEFORE INSERT = '||val);
 14
 15  END;
 16  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
TABLE COUNT BEFORE INSERT = 1

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         2

SQL>
```

So, you see `TABLE COUNT BEFORE INSERT = 1` and then after insert the count is 2.

Comment: Thanks, lalit but in my case there are multiple inserts in a  table which runs through a plsql block, i wanted to check the count of table before the insert and total count after the changes, but the problem i was facing is that trigger would fire on every insert , in that case my total  count before and after insert would be a problem.

Comment: You could have two triggers, one before insert another after insert. But, you need to make it autonomous transaction for after trigger. You could make it statement level trigger since you don't need to refer `:old` and `:new` values. You just need the count. But, why do you want the count after insert via trigger? All you need to do is, `select count(*)` after the insert statement, take it in a variable and use it.